# Select box with default option posting multiple values

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I was hoping someone could shed some light on a very odd behavior I've encountered. I have a simple select box (single value drop-down) that has a default selected value set on page load. The odd behavior is that if the user changes the value of the select box, it appears both values (the default value and the new selected value) are being sent on postback?!

```
<select name="selectBox">
    <option value="1" selected>Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

So, if a user selects item 2, on post I'm receiving a value like, `"1,2"`. Obviously, I'd expect just to receive a value of `"2"`. If I debug in firebug, when I select an option, the value being displayed in firebug is the single, selected value as expected. It seems so simple, am I blind? I am using MVC as the framework, if that makes any difference. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [`name`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/select/name) attribute to your [`select`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/select) element.

> The name attribute is used to reference form data after it’s
>   submitted, and to reference the data using JavaScript on the client
>   side. Unlike the id attribute, which must be given a unique value each
>   time it’s applied to a new form control, a name attribute with a given
>   value may be applied to numerous form controls (although in practice
>   this approach is only ever seen in use with radio input buttons).
>   **Note that only form elements which have a name attribute will have their values passed through to the page or script specified in the
>   form’s action attribute.**

Comment: Yes, sorry sorry, I typed it up too quickly. I DO have a name attribute.

Comment: Do you have more than one form on the page? Do you have multiple elements using the same `name` attribute?

Comment: just one form. all other fields have different `name` attribute

Comment: Oh! you are right. i just checked the page and one of our developers added a hidden input with the same name. thank you so much